# Error Call to a member function getRealPath() on bool

Tags: laravel

I am get this error"Call to a member function getRealPath() on bool"

```php
if($request->hasFile('content')) { 
    $filenameWithExt = $request->file('content')->getClientOriginalName(); 
    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME); 
    $extension = $request->file('content')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension; 
    $path = $request->file('content')->storeAs('public/content',$fileNameToStore); 
} else { 
    $fileNameToStore = 'No Image,Music and Video selected please! check and try again.'; 
}
```

```
$post = new Post;
 $post->body = $request->input('body');
 $post->content = $fileNameToStore;
 //Error exist here
 $post = Image::make($fileNameToStore->getRealPath());
 $post->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');
 $post->save();
```

Comment: where is `$fileNameToStore`defined?

Comment: can u post your $fileNameToStore defined codes.

Comment: if($request->hasFile('content'))
        {
          $filenameWithExt = $request->file('content')->getClientOriginalName();
          $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
          $extension = $request->file('content')->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
          $path = $request->file('content')->storeAs('public/content',$fileNameToStore);
        }
        else
        {
            $fileNameToStore = 'No Image,Music and Video selected please! check and try again.';
        }

Comment: It seems your $fileNameToStore is string, not bool, string do not have method ```getRealPath()``` too, do u miss somethings?

Comment: how do I figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

`getRealPath()` is the method of `SplFileInfo`

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getrealpath.php

If u want to use `getRealPath()`, try this:

```php
Image::make(
    $request->file('content')->getRealPath()
)->save('public/content',$fileNameToStore);
```